The integral of y dx was set equal to the integral of x dy (with a change of limits) in a derivation I was following. When is this justified?
The integral of y dx was set set equal to the integral of x dy (with a change of limits) in a derivation I was following. When is this justified?

Can you add more context?

It concerned the integral of 1/(1+x^2) dx.
